# Why does add-apt-repository fail to add source repositories?

Tags: apt

add-apt-repository throws an error if I try to add a source repository:

This works:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://dl.ajaxplorer.info/repos/apt squeeze main'
```

This fails with an error:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb-src http://dl.ajaxplorer.info/repos/apt squeeze main'
Error: 'deb-src http://dl.ajaxplorer.info/repos/apt squeeze main' invalid
```

Leaving off the quotes doesn't help:

```
sudo add-apt-repository deb-src http://dl.ajaxplorer.info/repos/apt squeeze main
Error: need a repository as argument
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [man page](http://man.he.net/man1/add-apt-repository) for `apt-add-repository` says (emphasis added):

> REPOSITORY can  be  either  a  line  that  can  be  added  directly  to        `sources.list(5)`,  or ...
>
> In  the   first   form,   **REPOSITORY   will   just   be   appended**   to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Now, while `deb-src` is a legal type for `sources.list` and you may wish to file a bug, it appears that this will do the job just as well, since GPG keys are only downloaded for PPAs:

```
sudo sh -c "echo deb-src http://dl.ajaxplorer.info/repos/apt squeeze main \ >> /etc/apt/sources.list"
```

Comment: It appears that add-apt-repository adds the deb-src line automatically, but this behavior has been flagged as a confirmed bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/987264

Answer (score 16):

If you want to add your repo as source repo as well you have to put the -s flag in the command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -s 'deb http://dl.ajaxplorer.info/repos/apt squeeze main'
```

And thats all.

This will add:

```
deb http://dl.ajax...
```

and

```
deb-src http://dl.ajax...
```

as well.

Comment: what if you want to only add `deb-src` because `deb` was there already?

Comment: you make a copy of the "deb" line, then you modify the first word from deb to deb-src